# Google Map Markers Numbering Start with 1 instead of 0

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps-markers, advanced-custom-fields

Is it possible to make the Markers on a Google Map start with #1 instead of 0.

I need to match the right side (Number and Name) to the left side (Map Markers)

Here's the Map URL:

https://waldorfastoriaresidencesbuckhead.com/living-in-buckhead/

Here's the code from the Restaurant Section: 
(it loads data from Custom Fields (uses the Advanced Custom Fields PRO plugin)

```
<?php if( have_rows('markers_restaurants', 2057)): ?>
                        <?php $count = 0; ?>
                        <?php while( have_rows('markers_restaurants', 2057) ): the_row(); 
                            // vars
                            $name = get_sub_field('name');
                            $latitude = get_sub_field('latitude');
                            $longitude = get_sub_field('longitude');
                            $count++;
                            ?>
                            <div class="" data-name="<?php echo $name; ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo $latitude; ?>" data-longitude="<?php echo $longitude; ?>">
                                <?php echo $count; ?> <?php echo $name; ?>
                            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions you may have.
Thanks!
Jackson

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but cannot you just compare to `marker number + 1` ?

Comment: Possibly also a stupid question, but why not move `$count++;` to below where you `echo $count?` That way both your stuff and Googles stuff will be zero indexed.

Comment: There are no stupid questions :) I moved the $count++; So now both the Lists and Markers start with 0. Hopefully the client will like that. Thank you for your suggestions!